# Get description of types in F# Interactive?

Tags: f#, types, f#-interactive

Can I get FSI.exe, the F# Interactive tool, to describe a type for me? In other words, there is a type I know how to access (specifically, IExpression in the Infer.NET library) but I do not know which methods it provides. I am hoping that I can use fsi to get a description of the available methods, properties, etc.

Can this be done, or is there a better way to go about it? I, sadly, do not have Visual Studio, which is how I used to get this information...

Thanks,
Nels

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This depends on what you mean by "describe", and how automated a process you are looking for.  It's quite easy to use the .NET reflection libraries to determine what public methods a type has.  For example:

```
typeof<System.String>.GetMethods()
```

will give you an array containing `MethodInfo`s for all of the public methods on the `String` class.  You can do exactly the same thing for any other types.

You can write a simple method to streamline the process:

```
let showMethods(t:System.Type) =
  t.GetMethods() |> Seq.iter (printfn "%A")
```

Comment: Thanks! This is basically what I was searching for. And as you probably know, similar methods exists like GetFields() and GetProperties().

Comment: (sorry for another answer suggesting VS - I missed the part that you do not have it).
Another useful tool in the absense of VS would be Reflector: http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/ - it gives you a nice UI for browsing types in assemblies